# LC lowpass filter optimization

Tags: filter, passive-networks, low-pass, passive-components

I have some 12 volt cooling fans which interfere with a radio transmitter. I notice that if I either put a large capacitor in parallel, or a large inductor in series, I can eliminate the noise heard on the transmissions from the 400mhz RF transmitter.

I want to have a capacitor-inductor pair (or maybe π or T filter) right in the "sweet spot" optimizing for smallest physical size.

What factors and design considerations should take place when optimizing for the right pair of L and C.

There are three 5 watt fans I am powering from 12vDC.

Comment: Can you specify more information about the fans?

Comment: http://www.kentuckyspecialfx.com/pa12v5wfanmu.html is a link to the fan

Comment: Simpler (and probably cheaper) to replace the brushless motor fan with a shaded pole motor fan that does not generate the RFI/EMI in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I found a new fan that is a lot nicer. The only problem with it is the spinning of the fan actually generates RF at the IF frequency so if it is near one of the RF modules on in the radio, it will interfere, and strangely, when the fan is slowing down after power removed, you will hear the slowing down!

Comment: It'll be hard to figure it out if you don't measure the spectrum of the junk that the fan is conducting out. You'd need to attach the fan to some line impedance stabilization network (LISN) and attach that to a spectrum analyzer. Then design a filter to suppress the stuff you don't want leaving the fan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sweet spot for surppressing noise from a DC motor would be right at the physical motor terminals.  One possibility for these types of flat fans is that you might be able to remove the center cover or label and see the internal motor contacts.  Sometimes you will see a disk cap soldered right to the motor terminals.  If there is none then it may be a good idea to add one there, (as large a value that will fit, at the proper voltage rating).

Unless you happen to know the actual frequencies to filter or the minumum tolerable noise level it is usually not practical to design an "optimised" LC circuit to filter out motor noise.  More often it is much better to over filter with the limits set only by the available space and reasonable cost of the parts.  As you should know any unwanted frequencies that happen get into an IF section of a radio can create noise at several other frequencies. So the more filtering the better.

The link you included shows a large electrolytic cap mounted to the fan housing.  It may be that the prior use of these fans also required significant noise filtering. If these caps were not included or removed from your fans it may be good to install them to see if that filters out enough of the noise.  The caps look to be at least a few hundred uF or more. Be sure to select parts rated above the 12v input supply.

If more filtering seems to be needed a simple double pi network on each fan could be tried. In this case each network would be placed as close as possible to the fan motor. I would use small metal core inductors of at least 1000uH in line with both the power and ground wires. Then place shunting capacitors (across power & ground) at both ends of the two inductors. You could even use an electrolytic and a ceramic cap in parallel at each end to be sure to get get better filtering at the low and high frequency ends.  Ceramic caps of at least 0.1uF should be used, the electrolytic can be in the hundreds of uF.

Be sure to select inductors with an adaquate current rating so as not to create any significant DC votage drop.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this problem regularly and fix it by adding a capacitor across the fan power terminals with series inductor to the incoming power.  Depending on the power requirements of the fan(s), I'll use an inductor that ranges in value from about 330uH on up to 1200uH.  The capacitor I use is a 100uF 35V AX or GX family part from Sanyo - we stock these capacitors for use in our SMPS power supplies and they work very well.

Ferrite-core inductors seem to work well.  The large inductors use Renco RB-4 or RB-5 cores wound with wire that ranges in size from 12 AWG on through 18 AWG.  This is for load currents in the range of 5A through 15A.

Smaller fans use a little ferrite bobbin-core inductor at 1200uH.  The DC resistance is a little high on these inductors but for small fans, it's not a problem.

I've never tried to optimize the capacitor size or type.  Basically, the first time I ran into this problem, I tried using the Sanyo very-low-ESR capacitors that we use in other products.  It worked *very* well - and that was that.

Answer (score 0):

Brushless DC fans are very noisey  and I like Dwaynes answer but I will add something          If you place a !ohm 2 watt metal film resister in series with the neg lead of the fan and connect the scope across the resister then you will see the terrible current waveform there are lots of artifacts in the hundreds of Hz ballpark corresponding to the rotation of the magnets triggering switching events  The low frequency noise needs bulkier electros and milly henries to even make a start on attenuating it  I have benched this BUT customers balked at the size of the parts so I feed all fans off a separate feeder to stop sensitive electronics getting upset  NOW there are some new Chinese fans with pwm built in which give switching frequency noise as well as the aforementioned low frequency rotational noise  I am too scared to put these pwm fans in uor mass spectrometer !  My website is for bad beetles ie ICs but maybe I should have it extended to other parts like  certain fans